# How to github custom domain on Hostgator?

Tags: github, dns

Im trying to have a custom domain for my github hosted blog, i changed the CNAME file to have my custom domain, head to my hostgator account, but i don't have access to the Cpanel, only a domain management dashboard where it only has a name server fields to edit, i suppose i need to change my DNS to the following:*

- 192.30.252.153
- 192.30.252.154
- CNAME username.github.io

*
However there is no way i can do that on Hostgator name server only dashboard.
where does the CNAME username.github.io goes ?

[Screen Shot to hostgator domain management dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE0Zw.png)

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Hostgator and asked them to edit my DNS information from their side and they were helpful and add the IP address and CNAME for me.
Problem Solved